# Generators of the ideal class group

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, computational-number-theory, class-field-theory

Theorem 4 of Eric Bach's *"Explicit bounds for primality testing and related problems"* states the following:

Let $K$ be a number field of degree greater than 1. Let $d$ be the absolute value of the discriminant of $K$. Let $\chi$ be a nonprincipal character of the ideals of $k$ that is defined modulo $\mathfrak{f}$. Then:
\begin{align*} 
\chi (p) &\neq 1 \text{  occurs for  }  N(\mathfrak{p}) \leq 3\log^{2}(d^2N(\mathfrak{f})) \\
\chi (p) & \neq 0,1 \text{  occurs for  }  N(\mathfrak{p}) \leq 12\log^{2}(d^2N(\mathfrak{f}))\\
\chi (p)  & \neq 0,1 \text{ and } \text{degree}(\mathfrak{p})=1  \text{  occurs for  }  N(\mathfrak{p}) \leq 18\log^{2}(d^2N(\mathfrak{f}))
\end{align*}

How do I get the result that the ideal class group is generated by the prime ideals of norm less than $12\log^{2}(d)$ from above theorem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $G$ be the ideal class group, and let $H$ be the subgroup generated by the prime ideals of norm at most $3\log^2(d^2)=12\log^2(d)$. Assume that $H$ is a proper subgroup of $G$. Then there is a nontrivial character of $G$ that is trivial on $H$. This character is trivial on the prime ideals of norm at most $3\log^2(d^2)=12\log^2(d)$, contradicting the first part of the theorem (with $\mathfrak{f}=\mathfrak{o}$). Hence $H=G$, and we are done.

Comment: If prime ideals of norm at most 3log^2(d) is enough for generating ideal class group, why do we come across the term 12log^2(d) in the literature?

Comment: @RashadEk I updated my response. The point is that $3\log^2(d^2)$ in Bach's theorem is the same as $12\log^2(d)$. If you like my answer, please accept it officially (so that it turns green). Thanks in advance!

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I have one more question. Erich Bach defined the characters on the prime ideals of ring of integers. In your proof you used a character on the ideal class group. How do we connect these two characters?

Comment: @RashadEk Eric Bach talks about characters of $\mathrm{Gal}(E/K)$ where $E/K$ is an abelian extension. By class field theory, the Galois groups of abelian extensions of $K$ can be identified (via the Artin reciprocity map) with quotients of ray class groups of $K$. In particular, the Galois group of the Hilbert class field of $K$ is isomorphic to the ideal class group of $K$. So what Eric Bach talks about includes the characters of the ideal class group of $K$. Note that the ideal class group itself is a quotient of the multiplicative group of nonzero fractional ideals of $K$.